# How to make scripts installed with pip from pyproject.toml file see imports?

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I'm trying to learn how to package scripts with poetry to be later installed via pip.

Here's a sample minimal `pyproject.toml`

```
name = "scripttest"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
packages = [ 
    { include = "src" }
]


[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
scripttest = 'src.scripttest:main'
```

Repository has following structure

```
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── importantimport.py
    └── scripttest.py
```

`scripttest.py` only has an import and a print statement

```
from importantimport import data
def main():
    print(data)
```

while `importantimport.py` contains a list inside

```
data = [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Running `python src/scripttest.py` yields expected output of
`[0, 1, 0, 1]`, but once installed via `pip install .`, running `scripttest` returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importantimport'`, despite `importantimport.py` being right next to it in `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/src`

How do I ensure that imports work locally after pip install?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want

```py
from scripttest.importantimport import data
```

This is because `importantimport` is package with your library, `scripttest`

Comment: This looks wrong to me.  `scripttest.py` and `importantimport.py` are "sibling" .py files in src.  There is no way that `from scripttest.importantimport import data` should work because `scripttest.importantimport` is not a submodule.

Comment: It's package within the pyproject.toml under the `scripttest` library namespace. You are right that there may be some unnecessary/confusing package metadata settings. I often prefer to use `src/<library_name>` with submodules underneath there so its much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Delete these lines:

```
packages = [ 
    { include = "src" }
]
```

Your project has no packages, only lone modules. Poetry's default discovery patterns will find the `importantimport.py` file.

Change these lines:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
scripttest = 'src.scripttest:main'
```

Into this:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
scripttest = 'scripttest:main'
```